# How do I get jumbotron outside container class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I understand I must place jumbotron class outside of container class for full width to take place. 
However, I'm not sure where to do this. Seems like I need to modify the php file somehow?

Thanks for your help!

I'm using front-page.php as my template for this page content.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

And here is my home page content:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://krystalpureh2o.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/slide-01.jpg" alt="slide-01" width="1210" height="450" class="img-responsive"/>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
             <h1>Professional Water Treatment</h1>
Reverse Osmosis | Water Softening | Whole House Filtration | Faucets | Filters | Connectors
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more »</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide-03.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="home">
<div class="span4">
<h2>WHY KRYSTAL PURE™</h2>
Krystal Pure™ offers the best water treatement equipment with longer warranties at lower prices than other similar nationally advertised brands.
<a class="btn" href="#">WATCH VIDEO »</a>

</div>
<div class="span4">
<h2>NEW KRYSTAL GUARD</h2>
Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
<a class="btn" href="#">SEE MORE »</a>

</div>
<div class="span4">
<h2>SUPPORT</h2>
Have questions about our products? Need to order a replacement part? Call us at 1-888-579-PURE (7873) or visit our support page.
<a class="btn" href="#">SUPPORT »</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the site...http://krystalpureh2o.com/wordpress/

Comment: Whats with all the ending `</p>` tags (validate your html), also your missing doctype

Comment: I added doctype. Not sure where those extra </p> tags are coming from. Don't see them in wordpress.

Comment: still not sure what to do about the html structure though...

Comment: never mind. I found a beginning container tag on header and a ending tag at beginning of the footer. Problem fixed.